# Q.Is Node Present in the binary Tree?[python] how to return True or false in the given code

Tags: python, return

Is Node Present in the binary Tree?[python] how to return True or false in the given code

```
def isNodePresent(root, x):
    if root is None:
        return 
    if root.data == x:
        return True
    isNodePresent(root.left, x)
    isNodePresent(root.right, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have a wrapper (if you cant change the code) that does the job of returning true or false

```py
def isNodePresent(root, x):
    if root is None:
        return
    if root.data == x:
        return root.data
    isNodePresent(root.left, x)
    isNodePresent(root.right, x)

def returnBooleanIfNodePresent(root, x):
    if isNodePresent(root, x) == None:
        return false
    else:
        return true
```

Hope that helps.